# Change the text color and background color of the links when hovered

Tags: css, colors, hover

I want to change the text color and background color of the links when hovered? The background color changes but the text does not change color

CSS:

```css
.choice-container { 
    display: flex; 
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem; 
    width: 100%; 
    font-size: 1.8rem; 
    color: rgb(255, 238, 0); 
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    border: 0.1rem solid rgb(255, 238, 0); 
}

.choice-container:hover { 
    cursor: pointer; 
    transform: translateY(-0.1rem);
    transition: transform 150ms; 
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important; 
    background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0); 
    border: 0.1rem solid rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    box-shadow: 0 0.4rem 2.4rem 0 rgb(255, 238, 0);
}
```

Comment: try to add !important after color

Comment: dont listen to that. `!important` is not a solution. Its a methode to get away with an issue without actually fixing the issue. It should only be used for templating if you have a standard design template and want to overwrite it.

Comment: run your code without !important and it works flawlessly. Have you already cleared your cache? typos with your HTML code? The CSS you provide has no error. It works fine, dont even have to use !important

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working without any error.

```css
.choice-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: rgb(255, 238, 0);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: 0.1rem solid rgb(255, 238, 0);
}

.choice-container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-0.1rem);
  transition: transform 150ms;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
  background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0);
  border: 0.1rem solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0.4rem 2.4rem 0 rgb(255, 238, 0);
}
```

```html
<a href = "https://www.google.com" class="choice-container">Google</a>
```

Here, it is in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kt1wzv08/

When not hovering:
[image]

When hovering:
[image]